# CMake STREQUAL returning false when it shouldn't

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compare the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID to expected IDs to set flags and such, but cmake is giving some pretty weird behavior. I am trying to do this:

```
message("Compiler ID: '${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}'")
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMIPLER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    message("Using GNU")
    set(warnings "-Wall")
    set(options "-std=c++11")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
    set(warnings "/W4 /XW /EHsc")
else ()
    message("wtf")
endif()
```

And I get the output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/sbin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/sbin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/sbin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/sbin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Compiler ID: 'GNU'
wtf
```

So apparently the compiler id is "GNU", but STREQUAL with "GNU" is false. Similar questions involve an out-of-date cache, but I have cleared it, so I don't think that is my issue. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMIPLER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
```

Should be

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
```

Comment: In addition, doing `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")` would be preferable due to CMake's implicit variable expansion in conditionals.

Comment: @Kikohs Thanks for pointing that out. I am so bad at reading things in all caps. I am the worst.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for the tip. Still figuring out the CMake syntax.

Comment: With the edit, it's actually worse. At least with the quotes, very new CMake would suppress implicit expansion. Either keep the quotes, or (preferably) get rid of the dereference altogether.